# EF6. Save exception information to database after rollback transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I need to save the information about an exception to the database.

i.e

```
SomeMethod() 
{
    try 
    {
         using(transaction = context.beginTransaction())
         {
             try 
             {
                 // here is the database error
                 await transaction.CommitAsync();
             } 
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 await transaction.Rollback();
                 throw;
             }
         } 
    }
    catch(Exception exception) 
    {
        // Here I get the same error that was generated inside the transaction
        context.Set<LogEntity>().Add(new LogEntity(....));
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    } 
}
```

Do I understand correctly that a context is a connection to a database and that in one context I can perform several transactions?

As I understand it, the context in this stage is in a dirty state?

How can I write to the database after a transaction error has occurred?

Comment: You're assuming the error wasn't a connection issue?

Comment: The Exception could also be due to the state of the entities that are associated with the DbContext in which case another call to SaveChanges will generate the same Exception. I would use a new DbContext instance for exception logging where the exceptions are possibly being generated by the DbContext.

Comment: yes, the error is related to the state of entities. 

I thought that rollback should also rollback the state of entities. 

At this stage, I created a transaction wrapper in which, when I call the rollback method, the state of the entities is rolled back, but I'm not sure what this is fraught with (I recently worked with ef).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand it, the context in this stage is in a dirty state?

Correct. The "database error" must have occurred in a `SaveChanges(Async)` call, so if you repeat that call on the same context, the exception will occur again. The remedy is simple: use a new context in the `catch` block.

Side note: catching the exception in the `using` block isn't necessary. If the transaction isn't committed before it's disposed, it will be rolled back.